# Discord.net can't add "digit" emoji reactions

Tags: c#, emoji, discord.net

I want to add reactions to a specific message with `AddReactionAsync`, and I want to use digit emojis (eg. 1️⃣,2️⃣, ...). The problem is that the BOT can't add these emojis, but it works fine with other emojis. 
**Code**

```
await IUserMessage.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji("1️⃣"));
await IUserMessage.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji("2️⃣"));
//...
await IUserMessage.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji("7️⃣"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the emojis like this instead:

```
new Emoji("3\u20e3")
```